# macOS - Getting SSL certificate error on valid certificate when accessing via git

Tags: git, ssl-certificate

2 days ago we started to get an error in git when pulling updates from our repository via HTTPs:

- "SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired"

Seems like a duplicate of the issue below, but because it's "git" and on "macOS Catalina 10.15.5" (the latest in June 2020) I am reporting this separately. I am not sure if git uses cURL or cURL uses something else that's outdated (quite frankly the resolution in "that" issue went straight over my head). I think people on Macs might need to be alerted of this.

git version 2.10.0 (thru 2.27.0 installed via homebrew)

Needless to say that Safari on macOS and iOS are reporting No errors. No issues with "git" on Windows 10 either.

Certificate Information:
The certificate is due to expire in a 18 months. Issued by "Sectigo RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA"

Possibly a duplicate of:
[Getting SSL certificate error on valid certificate when accessing via Curl](https://superuser.com/questions/1556491/getting-ssl-certificate-error-on-valid-certificate-when-accessing-via-curl)

Comment: This is almost certainly the same issue and the owner of the server needs to fix their certificate.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the [expiration](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/232445/https-connection-to-specific-sites-fail-with-curl-on-macos) of AddTrust Root CA 10 days ago.

I was able to resolve the same issue on my machine by [removing](https://gist.github.com/jmibanez/d3a5c97c44e5077edf00b9b68d60ed25) the `AddTrust` entry from `/etc/ssl/cert.pem`